# Launch sound only when recyclerview new item comes

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

So, I'm using firebase, and each time a new item populates my recyclerview I want to make a sound.

What I have done is to place an interface that will launch each time a new bind occours

### Adapter

```
 inner class ProductViewHolder(itemView: View) : BaseViewHolder<Product>(itemView) {
        override fun bind(item: Pedido, position: Int) {


                itemListener?.launchNotificationSound()

}
```

Now, in my view, I just play the sound with this interface

```
override fun launchNotificationSound() {
     mediaPlayer?.start()
  }
```

This works just fine !

But when I scroll, is obvious that the onBind will trigger again, so I'm looking for a way to just play this sound whenever a new item comes to the recyclerview, not always when its binded

Any suggestion ?

I'm using firebase firestore with realtime updates, so when I add a new element to my array it shows in realtime in the recyclerview, I just want to launch a sound once a new item is added

The problem is that if I play the sound on the realtime listener it will trigger also when the items are deleted and when new changes to that item are made in the database, and my goal is to just play the sound when new data comes only not when its updated

Answer (score 0):

You can add **DefaultItemAnimator** to recyclerview this way. Each time new item added to recyclerview, **onAddFinished** method triggered.

```
class MyDefaultItemAnimator(var music: MusicPlayer): DefaultItemAnimator() {
    override fun onAddFinished(item: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?) {
        super.onAddFinished(item)
        mediaPlayer?.start()
    }    
}
```

then add this to you recyclerview.

```
mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(MyDefaultItemAnimator())
```

Comment: Nice, this will not be triggered even when an item is removed from the recyclerview right ?

Comment: yes. can you please test and reply me. If works then accept this as an answer.

Comment: yes of course thanks ! Im testing, btw you forgot to pass to the defaultitemanimator the mediaplayer and the parameter is not musicplayer but instead mediaplayer

Comment: no, is not working this way, the sound is not played, I think is because the context of the execution, I will try changing it

Answer (score 0):

Since the sound is depending on adding an item to your data set, you can listen to data changes in your Adapter with `registerAdapterDataObserver` and override `onItemRangeInserted`,this callback will triggered by calling `notifyItemInserted()` so for example

**Register observer**

```
     customAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver(){

     override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
         super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount)
         playSound() // play your custom sound
     }
})
```

**Adding item to dataset in your** `Adapter`

```
dataSet.add("Added new element")
notifyItemInserted(dataSet.size)
```

Comment: I do not add by one item, instead I add by an entire list

Comment: @CoffeeBreak are you adding the entire list every time? or override the old one?